# I edited an audit, but it didn't return me to the review page

Tags: feature-request, bug, edits, review-audits

So I got suspicious when about a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36284456/how-to-adjust-x-axis-using-plot-when-range-is-changing-daily) in the first answer review queue, because it had the "potential spam" header. I actually clicked the link, realized it was an audit. I went back to the review page, but there was a missing apostrophe and I decided to edit the post anyway.

After I finished editing, I was sent to the actual page, instead of the review queue. I'm pretty sure that it essentially "skipped" the audit, because I only see a suggested edit in my actions history.

And now I'm here:

[image: history]

I assume this is a bug or some sort of hole in the system. I want to be taken back to the review page and be told I passed.