# Possible bug in reviewing Q & A First Posts

Tags: bug, review-queues

Please let me know if there's a duplicate or some other question this fits into.

I was reviewing a "First Question" for some small grammar items to clarify and someone else posted an edit to the title as I was reviewing it. (Actually, the edit was processed as I was finishing.)

I clicked the link in the header that appeared explaining there was a new edit, and proceeded to apply my edit. So far, so good.

But I was simply taken back to the post. Shouldn't I have been taken back to the review queue? If I'm to guess, the header link that informed me about an edit done while I was editing the same question didn't track where I was started from. Not a big deal - I'll continue reviewing questions in a moment - but this looks (to me) like a minor bug.

In case it matters, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43640026/unable-to-display-check-mark-in-particular-row-in-tableview) the question I was working on.

Comment: Potentially related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321583/i-edited-an-audit-but-it-didnt-return-me-to-the-review-page

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have introduced alternative state.  If you're saying that the edit appeared under the title like it usually does - just this time during your review, *and* you followed that link, then there's a likely chance that the page believed that you should, by default, be taken back to the post itself instead of the review.

I'm nowhere near an authority on this, but it does sound like aberrant behavior to me.

Comment: That's *exactly* what happened. I'm a relative newbie here (joined 10/16, attained 2k 04/17) so I have no idea if this is related to the site redesign. My instincts say no. Please, don't call this a "behavior"! :-) (Even though "aberrant behavior" sounds much better.)